# How to Count from sql as a value in Npsql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql, execute

I am using Npgsql to access postgresql database

and I am running a query:

```
int a = connection.Execute(@"SELECT count(*) FROM account AS a WHERE a.account_name = 'food'");
```

The query will return value 4, but my `a` gets -1.what is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using Dapper? If so you should tag it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Dapper. If so, you want `QueryFirst` not `Execute`, as `Execute` just returns the number of rows

```sql
int a = connection.QueryFirst<int>(@"
SELECT count(*)
FROM account AS a
WHERE a.account_name = 'food'
");
```